# How do I get TensorFlow to install on my computer? Pip install is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip, computer-vision

I am trying to run tensorflow for some simple computer vision recognition programs, however I get an error statement every time I try to install the library using Visual Studio Code. I am using Python 3.8. Below is the error I get when I try the pip install.

```
pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of pip?

Try running:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

first.

Otherwise, if you just want to try it out, Google Colab has tensorflow already installed. You can upload images you want Google Colab to process to Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the latest version of pip in order to install tensorflow. You can upgrade pip using the below command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

After upgrading Pip, it should work fine.